# Disqus API create post error

Tags: php, disqus

I have a problem using the Disqus API to try to comment on a publication made ​​in tumblr.
This is the code:

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

    $thread="XXXXXXXXX"; // e.g., 455718495 — you'll need to also create a $forum and pass that if you know only the thread's URL or identifier rather than the ID
    $api="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; // Generate one at http://disqus.com/api/applications/ -- Secret key is required for anonymous comment posting
    $message="Hello world."; // this is the content of the comment, i.e., what you'd normally type in the postbox
    $author_email="mail.user@mail.com"; // optional, including this will still make the comment a guest comment, but it will now be claimable 
    $author_name="user"; // optional, can be any display name you like
    $fields_string=""; // DO NOT EDIT

    // set POST variables
    $url = 'http://disqus.com/api/3.0/posts/create.json'; // full documentation at http://disqus.com/api/docs/posts/create/
    $fields = array(
        'api_secret'=>urlencode($api), // change to api_key when using a public key
        'thread'=>urlencode($thread),
        'message'=>urlencode($message),
        'author_email'=>urlencode($author_email),
        'author_name'=>urlencode($author_name),
    );

    foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
    rtrim($fields_string,'&');
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

    // execute POST
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    // close connection
    curl_close($ch);

?>
```

I pass the required values ​​as are the api_key, the message you wish to comment, the thread ID, the mail and username, when you run the code
php gives me the following error:

```
{"code": 4, "response": "You must be authenticated to perform this action"}
```

how can i solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Disqus API applications are now set to use OAuth so you have to add an 'access_token' argument to this example. There are two ways to get an the access token:

1. Use our OAuth flow and let the user log in with their Disqus account -- you won't include `author_name` or `author_email` if you use this method
2. Use your site owner access token (do this for guest comments like in your example above)

Here's the documentation on OAuth works with Disqus: http://disqus.com/api/docs/auth/ -- note that the site owner's access token can be found in your application overview here: http://disqus.com/api/applications/

Here's an example of how to let a user authenticate, and then give you an access token: https://github.com/disqus/DISQUS-API-Recipes/tree/master/php/oauth

Once you've acquired an access token, the script should look like this:

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

    $thread="XXXXXXXXX"; // e.g., 455718495 — you'll need to also create a $forum and pass that if you know only the thread's URL or identifier rather than the ID
    $api="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; // Generate one at http://disqus.com/api/applications/ -- Secret key is required for anonymous comment posting
    $message="Hello world."; // this is the content of the comment, i.e., what you'd normally type in the postbox
    $author_email="mail.user@mail.com"; // optional, including this will still make the comment a guest comment, but it will now be claimable 
    $author_name="user"; // optional, can be any display name you like
    $fields_string=""; // DO NOT EDIT
    $access_token="YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN";

    // set POST variables
    $url = 'http://disqus.com/api/3.0/posts/create.json'; // full documentation at http://disqus.com/api/docs/posts/create/
    $fields = array(
        'api_secret'=>urlencode($api), // change to api_key when using a public key
        'thread'=>urlencode($thread),
        'message'=>urlencode($message),
        'author_email'=>urlencode($author_email),
        'author_name'=>urlencode($author_name),
        'access_token'=>urlencode($access_token),
    );

    // rest of script ...
?>
```

Comment: You cannot use access_token and author_* parameters because if you are using acces_token you'll post comment as own content