# Can't post author_name with Disqus

Tags: c#, disqus

I'm getting the following error when trying to create a post

> This application cannot create posts on the chosen forum

I'm using my `public-key`, a thread identifier and `author_name` and `author_email` and a message. When I'm using my `accessToken` I can insert comments, but can't use `author_name` and it will always post under your name, because of the `accessToken`.

But I'm converting my weblog from WordPress to a static web site and I'm trying to insert comments from my blog to `Disqus`. So I need to insert `author_name` for comments that I didn't write myself. But that's where I fail.

I keep getting errors. I'm building this in C# and tried adding referrer Http headers, but that also fails. Although it sometimes gives another error. But the following screenshot shows what I'm trying to do from the [Disqus website](https://disqus.com/api/console/#!/). Any idea how to properly insert a comment with `author_name`?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15436011/68939 ? Did you check the points there mentioning "trusted domains"?

Comment: I did, yeah. The only thing I can't do on that Disqus website is set the referer. But in my C# code I am adding that.